# Group an Array object base on specific values

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects

```
data: [
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem1",
          name: "John",
          age: 50,
        },
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem1",
          name: "Justin",
          age: 34
        },
        {
          category: "cat2",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          name: "Mark",
          age: 34
        },
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          name: "Jason",
          age: 56
        }
      ]
```

I have to group it according to the `category` and `categoryItem`. Is there any way I can format it like this:

```
data: [
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem1",
          items: [
            {
              name: "John",
              age: 50,
            },
            {
              name: "Justin",
              age: 34
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          category: "cat2",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          items: [
            {
              name: "Mark",
              age: 34
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          items: [
            {
              name: "Jason",
              age: 56
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO (there are **lots** of these), and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and group by category and catergoryItem and in last you can take `Object.values`:

```js
const data= [
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem1",
          name: "John",
          age: 50,
        },
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem1",
          name: "Justin",
          age: 34
        },
        {
          category: "cat2",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          name: "Mark",
          age: 34
        },
        {
          category: "cat1",
          categoryItem: "catItem2",
          name: "Jason",
          age: 56
        }
      ];
      
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a,{category, categoryItem,...rest})=>{
    const key = `${category}|${categoryItem}`;
    (a[key] ??={category, categoryItem,items:[]}).items.push(rest);
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```